# Why .click() was not triggered after confirming on sweet alert?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, sweetalert2

I am trying to create a reusable function in javascript to call on buttons that require user confirmation.

I already have this code on my Master Page in WebForms.

```
function sweetAlertConfirm(btn, title, msg, icon) {
    if (btn.dataset.confirmed) {
        // The action was already confirmed by the user, proceed with server event
        btn.dataset.confirmed = false;
        return true;
    } else {
        // Ask the user to confirm/cancel the action
        event.preventDefault();
        Swal.fire({
            icon: icon,
            title: title,
            text: msg,
            showDenyButton: true,
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
            denyButtonText: `No`,
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                // Trigger the button click event to proceed with the server event
                btn.dataset.confirmed = true;
                btn.click();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And I am implementing it on my LinkButton like this.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Style="margin-right: 10px;" ID="cmdDeleteGoal"
   CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "GoalCode") %>'
   OnClientClick="return sweetAlertConfirm(this, 'Delete Goal?', 'Do you want to delete this goal?', 'question');"
   OnClick="cmdDeleteGoal_Click"  >
   <i class="fa-solid fa-trash text-danger" data-bs-toggle="tooltip"
      data-bs-placement="top"
      title="Delete Goal"></i>
</asp:LinkButton>
```

CODE BEHIND

```
LinkButton cmdDeleteGoal = (LinkButton)sender;
                bool _converted = int.TryParse(cmdDeleteGoal.CommandArgument, out int goalCode);
               
                if (!_converted) { 
                    ShowToast("", "#00ff00");
                    return;
                }

                _systemProcess = new DeleteGoalLogic();
                _userInput = new UserInput()
                {
                    KRACode = 1,
                    GoalCode = goalCode
                };
                _systemResult = _systemProcess.DoProcess(_userInput);

                ShowToast(_systemResult.Message, (_systemResult.ResultCode == SystemResult.ResultCode_Success ? "#00ff00" : "#ff0000"));
```

this is the element rendered in HTML

```
    <a id="_bodyContent_rptrGoals_cmdDeleteGoal_0"
        href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$_bodyContent$rptrGoals$ctl00$cmdDeleteGoal','')" 
        style="margin-right: 10px;">
           <i class="fa-solid fa-trash text-danger" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" aria-label="Delete Goal" data-bs-original-title="Delete Goal"></i>
   </a>
```

Now, the scenario is, The sweetalert is showing, and after I confirm on sweet alert. `btn.click();` was not triggered.

I already tried `console.log('test')` inside this code

```
if (result.isConfirmed) {
    // Trigger the button click event to proceed with the server event
    btn.dataset.confirmed = true;
    btn.click();
}
```

and it works properly.

Now, my question is, What am I doing wrong and How can I successfully trigger the btn.click if the user confirms?

Comment: Please ,replace your asp.net code by rendered html code from browser.

Comment: And  what is the code from function `__doPostBack()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the event prevent default.

So, let's make a working example.

Do not use the prevent default.

Say we have a Grid view, link button click.

So, this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" Width="50%">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"    />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"  />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDeleteHotel" 
                        ToolTip="Delete this file"
                        runat="server"
                        OnClick="cmdDeleteHotel_Click"
                        OnClientClick="return sweetAlertConfirm(this, 'Delete Hotel?', 'Delete this hotel?', 'question');"
                        >
                            <span class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></span>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

code to load, and link delete button code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    GHotels.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName")
    GHotels.DataBind()

End Sub

Protected Sub cmdDeleteHotel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As LinkButton = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer

    Debug.Print("Row index = " & gRow.RowIndex)
    Dim intPK As Integer = GHotels.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblHotels WHERE ID = @ID")
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intPK
    'MyRstPE(cmdSQL)
    Debug.Print($"Will delete {intPK}")

End Sub
```

And the script is this:

```
        <script>
            function sweetAlertConfirm(btn, title, msg, icon) {

                if (btn.dataset.confirmed) {
                    // The action was already confirmed by the user, proceed with server event
                    btn.dataset.confirmed = false;
                    return true;
                } else {
                    // Ask the user to confirm/cancel the action

                    swal(msg, {
                        buttons: ["No", "Yes"],
                    }).then((willDelete) => {
                        if (willDelete) {
                            // Trigger the button click event to proceed with the server event
                            btn.dataset.confirmed = true;
                            btn.click();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            }
```

The result is this:

[image]

output:

```
Row index = 5
Will delete 3
```

So, you return a true or false. The above works fine as a proof of concept.

Clean up your code, your cut + paste, or code has all kinds of errors.

```
 Swal --- no, it lower case!!! swal(.....
```

and this:

```
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
```

should be this:

```
  }).then((result) => {
     if (result) {
```

So, yes, remove the prevent default.

Just return a true, or false to control running of the server side button.

Your click probably does not work due to errors in your js code.

## Edit#2: using sweet alert 2

So, I now have this, same code really, and it still works just fine.

Remember, it is the CONCEPTS you want to learn here.

So, say we have this:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10"></script>

<asp:GridView ID="GHotels" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" Width="800px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"    />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"  />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description"  />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="cmdDeleteHotel" 
                        ToolTip="Delete this file"
                        runat="server"
                        OnClick="cmdDeleteHotel_Click"
                        OnClientClick="return sweetAlertConfirm(this);"
                        >
                        <span class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg"></span>
                    </asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


        <script>
            function sweetAlertConfirm(btn) {

                if (btn.dataset.confirmed) {
                    btn.dataset.confirmed = false;
                    return true;
                }

                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Are you sure?',
                    text: "Delete This Hotel?",
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
                    cancelButtonText: 'No, Cancel',
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        // Trigger the button click event to proceed with the server event
                        btn.dataset.confirmed = true;
                        btn.click();
                    }
                })
                return false;
            }
        </script>
```

And once again, our code behind is this:

```
Protected Sub cmdDeleteHotel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim btn As LinkButton = sender
    Dim gRow As GridViewRow = btn.NamingContainer
    Dim intPK As Integer = GHotels.DataKeys(gRow.RowIndex).Item("ID")

    Dim cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID = @ID")

    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = intPK
    MyRstPE(cmdSQL)
    LoadGrid()  ' update gv to show deleted

End Sub
```

And I as noted, UN-commented out the delete command, and removed the debug.prints.

And results are now this:

[image]

Comment: This wont work, I already tried this, The purpose of this is to bypass the postback as soon as the user click on the link button. doing this will both trigger onclick and onclient click at the same time. My goal here is to ask the user first before triggering the server event.

Comment: see my working posted code - it shows proof of concept and does work just fine. If you return a true value, then button click + server side code runs. but, returning false, then server side button event does not trigger. the key concept here is that jQuery.UI dialogs, or sweet-alert does not halt code (they run asynchronous). But, as above shows, you can without much effort return true or false, and re-fire the button again.

Comment: You might be wondering how this can and does work? What happens is when you click the button, the dialog pops up code runs though (does not halt), returns false, server side code does not run. If user answers ok, then we set our persisting value = true, AND CLICK the button again. Since this time, the value is true, we return a true value and the server side code runs. So, we in effect wind up running the button click 2 times. As long as we return false, that don't matter. However the instant we return true, then server side code behind runs.  This gets around having to use js await or promise

Comment: Thank you for your answers, But I think you're missing some important things. sweetalert and sweelalert2 are different versions. I tried using the first version, and the code I posted here works fine. But when it comes to the sweetalert2. It does not. As I saw your example, The row you are trying to delete does not also triggering the server event. which is the main problem.

Comment: yes, my example code DOES trigger the server event if you answer yes, and if you answer no, then the server side code does not run. In my sample code, I had commented out the actual delete code - it was just for testing, but I DID show the output and print commands from the server code. As noted, the above works. I can try sweetalert 2 - I suspect it will work just the same. Perahps the syntax of sweet2 is a bit different, but I have little doubt it about it also working using the above approach. I'll download and try sweet2, and see if it works.

Comment: Your effort and help, I highly appreciate it. Thank you Sir.

Comment: See my 2nd edit - I show a working example with sweeta2, and it works just the same. As I stated, the above outlined approach works with jquery.UI dialogs, or sweet-alert, or sweet-alert2 or whatever. The server side button ONLY fires when we setup the code to return true.

Comment: No problem,  now that you have proof of concept,  then start adding back your several parameters and get them to work.  Good luck. I'm happy to post c# code if you wish.